# Gesture detection in Flutter TextSpan

Tags: gesture, flutter

Is there a way to detect which word in the `TextSpan` was touched by the user?

This paragraph is here to get round the stack overflow robot that is insisting that I write more stuff :)

Answer (score 230):

You can improve by yourself

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
...

RichText(
      text: TextSpan(text: 'Non touchable. ', children: [
        TextSpan(
          text: 'Tap here.',
          recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = () => print('Tap Here onTap'),
        )
      ]),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to import package 'gestures.dart';
After using import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart'; it got worked for me..

Comment: Remember that events triggered is only effective to `text` and not any of TextSpan provided in `children`.

Comment: Why do you use ".." instead of "." ?

Comment: How would you test this? If it's a RichText with multiple TextSpan and one of them is a tappable TextSpan, how would you tap it during a test?

Comment: How about calling `dispose()` method of `TapGestureRecognizer`? Is it necessary?

Comment: Do you know how to have both onTap and onLongPressed? Thank a lots.

Answer (score 102):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

Use `recognizer` property of `TextSpan` which allows almost all types of event.

```dart
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(
        text: 'Single tap',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red[300]),
        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = () {
          // Single tapped.
        },
      ),
      TextSpan(
        text: ' Double tap',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green[300]),
        recognizer:  DoubleTapGestureRecognizer()..onDoubleTap = () {
          // Double tapped.
        }
      ),
      TextSpan(
        text: ' Long press',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[300]),
        recognizer: LongPressGestureRecognizer()..onLongPress = () {
          // Long Pressed.
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: How do you pass the underlined text to the method which processes taps?

Comment: I suggest that you put the text in a variable and then you can use it in the tap handling closure @AlexSemeniuk

Comment: @jlyonsmith Yeah, I ended up doing exactly that: creating a map which links recognizers to their values, and filling it along the way. Can't think of any better solution.

Answer (score 10):

Iterate over the string to get an array of strings, create separate text span for each and add the gesture recognizer

```
 List<TextSpan> createTextSpans(){
    final string = """Text seems like it should be so simple, but it really isn't.""";
    final arrayStrings = string.split(" ");
    List<TextSpan> arrayOfTextSpan = [];
    for (int index = 0; index < arrayStrings.length; index++){
      final text = arrayStrings[index] + " ";
      final span = TextSpan(
        text: text,
        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = () => print("The word touched is $text")
      );
      arrayOfTextSpan.add(span);
    }
    return arrayOfTextSpan;
```

Comment: why this double dot?

Comment: you can read more about it [here](https://fluttermaster.com/method-chaining-using-cascade-in-dart/)

Answer (score 3):

```
late TapGestureRecognizer tapGestureRecognizer;

@override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
    
      tapGestureRecognizer = TapGestureRecognizer()
        ..onTap = () {
          widget.onProfileDetails();
        };
    }
    
    @override
    void dispose() {
      super.dispose();
      tapGestureRecognizer.dispose();
    }
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Flexible(
        child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: widget.notificationObject.name,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: width * 0.044,
                  fontFamily: 'HelveticaNeueRegular',
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),
                recognizer: tapGestureRecognizer,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

Comment: This is the best way because it prevents a memory leak by disposing of the TapGestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  text: "If you don't have a account ",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: AppFonts.phagsPa,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: AppColors.white,
                  ),
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text: "sign-up".toUpperCase(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: AppColors.btnBgColor,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                      recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                        ..onTap = () {
                          Get.to(() => MerchantSignupPage());
                        },
                    ),
                    TextSpan(text: " here")
                  ],
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
```

Comment: Above solutions give error: Missing selector such as '.identifier' or '[0]'.  Try adding a selector.