# GestureDetector on text span without line break

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to put GestureDetectors on single phrases in a text block.
While it does work, I don't want the GestureDetector to create a new line. What I want is more like a text-link in html. Somehing like the following code gives me 3 seperate lines, how do I get a single line?

```
    Text(
        'This ',
      ),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          doSomething();
        },
        child: Text(
          'text ',
        ),
      ),
      Text(
        "should be in one line.",
      ),
```

EDIT:

[image]

```
Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Short text"),
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Text(
                      "Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. "),
                ),
                Text("Short text"),
                Text(
                    "Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. Very long text. ")
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

While the solution suggested in the comments yields something like this:

[image]

That's what I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you still have issues with the solution provided below. Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks, but for longer texts I get something like the last screenshot above.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of how you want it to look like (final screen)?

Comment: added a screenshot

Comment: First you can't do it using `Row` or `Column` you need to use `RichText`.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction, will look into that

Comment: I updated the code, take a look now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var underlineStyle = TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline, color: Colors.black);

// ...

RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Basically what I want is a block of text with certain ',
    style: underlineStyle.copyWith(decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'elements ', style: underlineStyle),
      TextSpan(text: 'allowing for '),
      TextSpan(text: 'clicks ', style: underlineStyle),
      TextSpan(text: 'or '),
      TextSpan(text: 'drag gestures', style: underlineStyle ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image]

Comment: That's it. Combined with TapGestureRecognizer() [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914775/gesture-detection-in-flutter-textspan) I can build what I want

Comment: Ye, there is `recognizer` property in `TextSpan` and it is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Row` instead `Column` as a parent, it should work.

```
  Row(
            children: [
              Text(
                'This ',
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  doSomething();
                },
                child: Text(
                  'text ',
                ),
              ),
     Expanded( child: 
              Text(
                "should be in one line.",
                 ),),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: Thanks, this does provide me with one line but it overflows to the right if it's too long. I'm looking for a solution that is constrained to the view size/width, just not wrap at each GestureDetector.

Comment: Just wrap the last child using Expanded

Comment: it's still overflowing, only the yellow/black overflow thingy is getting taller (is lineheight without the Expanded and gets taller with the Expanded)

Comment: Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: So after cleaning up my code the overflow disappeared (not sure what it was), but anyway, I couldn't solve my initial problem. Will add a screenshot to my post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have clickable text in some portion of your paragraph.

I hope [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/quicktip-converting-text-urls-into-clickable-hyperlinks-2bb2d3b3b4b2) helps.

Comment: Thanks but I need GestureDetector for gestures other than clicks too.