How can I set the privacy policy URL for the Health Connect permissions screen in a Flutter app
HealthConnect screenshot
I am developing a cross-platform app using Flutter, but I'm encountering issues with integrating Health Connect. I want to display a custom URL when the user clicks the "Privacy Policy" button. This is my first time posting a question, and I need to ensure it is long enough. I believe I've explained it clearly, but I'm not sure how else to express it. Please click top link to view the screenshot.

Please have a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914775/gesture-detection-in-flutter-textspan

This seems like a viable solution, but is there a more direct way? For example, would Google Health Connect provide a callback function when I click on the text in the screenshot?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can use RichText like the following
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Clickable Text Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: CustomText(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomText extends StatelessWidget {
  // URL to be opened
  final Uri _url = Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev');

  // Function to launch URL
  Future<void> _launchUrl() async {
  if (!await launchUrl(_url)) {
    throw Exception('Could not launch $_url');
  }
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        children: [
          TextSpan(
            text: 'Click ',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
          ),
          TextSpan(
            text: 'here',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 18, decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
            recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = _launchUrl,
          ),
          TextSpan(
            text: ' to open the link.',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Please add url_launcher dependency too
https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

Thank you for your reply. However, the screenshot shows a permissions screen outside of the app, which doesn’t seem to be directly controllable in the code

You can pass launch mode to open it within the app. Check this url. https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/url_launcher/LaunchMode.html

@KaushikChandru as you can see from the provided screenshot the Health Connect Permissions screen is not created with Flutter so your solution isn't applicable.
